# Starting eclipse with configured JVM from windows batch file

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file

I have problems to start eclipse with a proper configured JVM from windows batch file.
I like to do it this way, because I have different workspaces, different eclipse versions, different java versions and different configurations.

I guess  the problem is the way  I pass the parameters. I have tried several combinations of setting '"', but none worked. Below is just one example.

Anyway, can someone help?
Thanks :-)

Afterwards added:
Sorry, I forgot - the problem is the parameters for the JVM are neglected

```
@echo off
ver
echo.

set thePathToJDK=C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.10x9-hotspot

rem to be checked - is JAVA_HOME needed by anyone ?
rem eclipse states that is neglecting JAVA_HOME
set JAVA_HOME=%thePathToJDK%

rem set path to vm ( shall be in harmony with path to JDK )
set thePathToJVM=%thePathToJDK%\bin\javaw

set thePathToEclipse=C:\eclipse\ ...

set thePathToEclipseWorkSpace=C:\ ...

rem set minimal path (for ECLIPSE/JAVA)
set theNewPath=%SystemRoot%\system32
set theNewPath=%theNewPath%;%SystemRoot%
set theNewPath=%theNewPath%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
set theNewPath=%theNewPath%;%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set path=%thePathToJDK%\bin;%theNewPath%
echo.
echo path used for ECLIPSE
echo %path%

set theCommand=%thePathToEclipse%\eclipse.exe   -data "%thePathToEclipseWorkSpace%"   -vm "%thePathToJVM%"   -vmargs -ea -Xmx4096m -Xss256m
echo.
echo %theCommand%

rem start eclipse with preconfigured Java
cmd /c %theCommand%

pause
```

Comment: You have not asked a question.  When you ran the script, what happened?  What did it do and what did it not do?

Comment: The Java you use to run Eclipse has nothing to do with the Java you use to compile and run programs within Eclipse. You should not need to change the Eclipse Java.

Comment: @cliff2310 sorry, it was copy paste error and got lost

Comment: @greg-449 
Uuups, with -vmargs I configured the java to run eclipse?
This is/was not my purpose. I want to configure the Java to compile and run programs within Eclipse.
But it explains "neglectation" of parameters.

Comment: All those parameters only change the Java that Eclipse itself uses. They have nothing to do with the settings for Compiling and running projects - those can't be set from the command line. Eclipse always uses its own Java compiler (not the JDK compiler) using the settings in the project properties. If you want to compile things from a batch file you should use [tag:maven]

Comment: First of all, THANKS to everyone that was trying help.


Ok, to be honest, I am not an expert for eclipse.
Even so I do not want to become an expert for eclipse - sorry.
I just want the job to get done.


E.g. I want to start some batch file telling eclipse
this time use java 15 for compilation
and execute with Adopt Open JDK 15.0.2+7, enable assertions, use 1GByte memory for stack and heap.
That's just an example - next time I start another batch file configuring other things.
I can not configure this from command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @greg-449 pointed out, "the parameters" only change the Java that Eclipse itself uses.
What I wanted cannot be done the way I wanted it to be done
:-(

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you need to include the `.exe` part of the VM's file name when you're using `-vm` with a file rather than a folder.